# ReactJS: How to I create selectable Child Form that passes data back to Parent form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My Apologies for being vague, but I do not know how better I can explain this situation. I am learning `ReactJS` and `JS` as well. I am working on a project where I have following Requirement.

- There is a Form where user can add text, numbers
- There is a DropDown Menu (I am using Material UI - http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu) which once clicked opens a new Page/component
- This Child Page/Component has List Data and user must be able to pick one of the items in it.
- Once clicked, the data goes back to Parent Component and Child Page disappears.

Visually, I found an example of how it should work  http://recordit.co/GIDxCbD28X

[image]

I am looking for guidance on how to build this workflow. Again, apologies for open-ended question, but I hope to get help on this. Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about 'lifting state'? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I'd suggest to use Redux, or any unidirectional dataflow model. http://redux.js.org/

Comment: sounds more like the parent should just pass down a method to the child

Answer (score 0):

You keep the selection from DropDown Menu in your Form component state. Form component has a method that sets this state to a new value. You pass this method down to DropDown Menu as a prop. DropDown menu calls this method when the user selects an item.

You should probably also keep the boolean that tells you whether DropDown Menu page/modal/whatever is visible or not, so the method that handles selection of an item can both set that flag to false and set the selected item to a new value with one setState() call.